how can I display the create statement of a table in a database I am accessing?
I have a database with a table that I can see the data but I need to see the create statement which created the table.  I can do this in SQL server but dont see how in Snowflake.
I tried right clicking on the table name and expanding the  boxes and dont see the create statement.

I don't know snowflake, but if you can export you table, you can see the CREATE statement.

Good idea but I can't find a way in SNOWFLAKE to export the table.

If you don't know that this will work, it should be a comment to the question rather than an answer.

If you want to retrieve DDL of object in Snowflake you can do so in 2 ways:
use GET_DDL() function
. In your case the syntax would be:
select get_ddl('table', 'table_name')
Notice that table name is enclosed in ''.¸
Using GUI
Navigate to Data in left menu -> locate the table in question -> click table name -> Table definition is displayed
Alternatively: Within Project - Worksheet locate the table in left menu (within databases tab): click on 3 dots next to the table name -> select view definition from dropdown menu
